# How to save image after edit in php

Tags: php, javascript, pixastic

I have create a simple image editor with the effects of brightness, contrast, and desaturation etc. I have used for this pixastic functions from www.pixastic.com. The function is working successfully but I don't know how to replace the original image with the adjusted image, with effects. Here is code I have used

```
<script>
var pixastic_parseonload = true;
</script>
<script src="pixastic.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="actions/desaturate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
<form name="form1" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" class="pixastic <?php echo @$_POST["butn1"];?>" src="Desert.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277" name="image1">
<button value="pixastic-desaturate()" name="butn1" >Desaturate</button>
</form>
</bode>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to change this:

```
<button value="pixastic-desaturate()" name="butn1" >Desaturate</button>
```

with this:

```
<input type="button" name="pixastic-desaturate" VALUE="Click to process the image" onClick="pixastic-desaturate();">
```

Comment: Thanks. but this is not working. I want to save image after effects.

Comment: I did not understand the question correctly. Isnt there any predefined function in the package to do the job for you?